# Arch Linux Realtek bluetooth controller not detected

Tags: arch-linux, bluetooth

Bluetoothctl is not detecting my realtek bluetooth controller.

Output of ls `/dev | grep hci`

```
vhci
```

Output of `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`

```
[    3.203531] usb 4-10: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[    3.689235] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.689259] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.689264] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.689267] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.689272] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.720373] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: examining hci_ver=08 hci_rev=826c lmp_ver=08 lmp_subver=a99e
[    3.720377] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rtl: unknown IC info, lmp subver a99e, hci rev 826c, hci ver 0008
[   59.402999] audit: type=1130 audit(1547348479.153:37): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=bluetooth comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'
[   59.413396] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   59.413398] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   59.413404] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1532:0502 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 062a:5918 MosArt Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 0bda:b00a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `bluetoothctl` and then typing `power on`

```
No default controller available
```

The `bluetooth` service is currently running

I am a member of the `lp` group

Output of `lsmod | grep btusb`

```
btusb                  57344  0
btrtl                  20480  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                28672  1 btusb
bluetooth             651264  12 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
```

I have the `bluez` package installed and I have tried both `bluex-utils` and `bluez-utils-compat`

*Edit* The bluetooth controller `hci0` is detected by the kernel but bluetoothctl does not find it.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

*Edit #2* I have figured out that in `hciconfig` hci0 is down but if I run `hciconfig hci0 up` it returns `Can't init device hci0: Invalid argument (22)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you happen to have RTL8821CE wireless + bluetooth combo?

There's a solution for Arch about this problem on the AUR package's Github.
https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce/issues/19#issuecomment-451890849

I'm hoping it's a temporary problem due to some other bug because someone said it began working again.
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201921#c1

Comment: The kernel patch that was suggested in that github issue fixed it :)